# Is there a good reason to have multiple Ansible inventories (over one inventory for all hosts)?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

When first creating Ansible inventories I created separate files roughly separated by roles, but in one directory. So my directory structure looks like this (with made up roles):

```
ansible\
  inventory\
    dbservers
    logservers
    webservers
  host_vars\
  roles\
```

This made it easy to run a playbook on all DB servers or all web servers, for example, but I realise now that I could also do this by using host groups (which I already have anyway).

One problem I'm running into now is that I want to list the hosts in one inventory while running a playbook on another. For example, dbservers might have a firewall rule to allow access from webservers and I want to do `lookup('inventory_hostnames', 'webservers')` - but that doesn't work when the "webservers" group is defined in the "webservers" inventory and I'm running with `-i inventory/dbservers`. Another problem is that host groups for things other than roles, such as the physical locations of the servers, are duplicated between files.

To solve this I'm tempted to just move everything into one inventory. Are there any downsides to doing this?

(I'm aware that I can run with `-i inventory_dir` so I can still have multiple inventory *files* but use them as one logical inventory.)

Answer (score 1):

Every solution has its pros and cons.

Of course, if you have 2 dbservers, 1 log and 3 webserver, then having all 6 of them declared in one file is OK.
However, when you manage bigger system, you may have 100s of server. In that case separating them is more benefical and less error prone.

So, if the question is which way is better, then there is no answer. Everybody have their own preference.
If the question is is it bad to have all servers declared in one file. Then the answer is no. As long as you stay organized and that the situation suits you well.

Comment: Yes, obviously the file can get large. My question was really whether there are other downsides, e.g. things I could do with multiple files, but not with a single file.

Comment: Hmm I've never encountered a situation where I could do something with one inventory file and not with multiple files (and vice versa). I'm not aware of any situation like this... But it doesn't mean it could not exists. Also, the documentation does not seems to mention this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "right way" or "wrong way", but let me provide a couple of insights from what we've done in deploying Ansible over the past few years.

We use separate inventories to indicate production vs staging or test, which has served us well. In this way, we use groups to represent different machine roles (not to be confused with Ansible roles) within the playbooks, but we can easily switch between production and staging.

Inside of the inventories, we set certain standard variables and groups which allow for easy determination of whether we're addressing test machines or production machines.

This way, when we run a playbook, we use something such as:

```
ansible-playbook -i prod name-of-playbook.yml
```

and replace the `prod` with `stage` if we're running it over the stage machines.

This isn't going to be everyones solution, but it's been very effective for us.

A standard inventory file for us would look something like:

```
[db-servers]
db1.foo.net

[web-servers]
web.foo.net

[all:vars]
env: prod
```

Then we'd use `db-servers` and `web-servers` in the plays within the playbook and be able to check `env` where necessary if we need to know whether we're using production or staging systems.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned both works and both have their limitations.
We work with separate inventories for our stages: DEMO TEST etc.
Mainly to have a clear separation of the stages to avoid accidentally missconfigurations.
And application of plays. Also you have to explicitly set the inventory you want to work with.
The main disadvantage you have when you use several inventorys is that you have to set vars  layout changes( groups childs etc.) multiple times.

Now its up to you :)